# Reverse ng-list effect

Tags: angularjs, mongoose

I am using [`ng-list`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/api/ng/directive/ngList) directive on some text inputs to store values as an array (separated by `\n`) to mongoose schema. and it works fine so far.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="textfield" ng-list="/\n/" />
```

The problem is when the data comes back from the server, angular automatically joins the array elements with a comma (on initial binding), and i wanna have them separated by `\n`. How can I do that?

I use angular 1.3

Comment: try `<input type="text" ng-model="textfield" ng-list="/\n/" ng-init="textfield.split(",").join("\n")"  />`

Comment: On server side after you pulled the data using mongoose it is still an array seperated by \n? only after it is being sent to the client angular manipulates the array using comma to seperate?

Comment: @OrGuz; the data is being saved to mongoose as an array of strings. and being retrieved by the api in an array format `["a", "b", "c"]` and is show in the text field like `a,b,c`

Comment: The examples of ngList are using `ng-list="&#10;"` on a **textarea** to have the newline as a separator. Putting `ng-list="/\n/"` in a plunk uses this string without escaping as a separator. See http://plnkr.co/edit/UFOzV2zCBTtZuS1Jztay?p=preview